# How do I achieve this in Apache Spark Java or Scala?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset, apache-spark-2.0

A device on a car will NOT send a TRIP ID when the trip starts but will send one when the TRIP ends. How do I apply corresponding TRIP IDS to the corresponding records

```
09:30,25,DEVICE_1
10:30,55,DEVICE_1
10:25,0,DEVICE_1,TRIP_ID_0
11:30,45,DEVICE_1
10:30,55,DEVICE_2
10:30,55,DEVICE_3
11:30,45,DEVICE_3
12:30,0,DEVICE_3,TRIP_ID_3
10:30,55,DEVICE_4
11:30,45,DEVICE_4
11:30,45,DEVICE_2
12:30,0,DEVICE_2,TRIP_ID_2
12:30,0,DEVICE_4,TRIP_ID_4
10:30,55,DEVICE_5
11:30,45,DEVICE_5
12:30,0,DEVICE_5,TRIP_ID_5
12:30,0,DEVICE_1,TRIP_ID_1
```

So the above becomes like this,

```
09:30,25,DEVICE_1,TRIP_ID_0
10:25,0,DEVICE_1,TRIP_ID_0
10:30,55,DEVICE_1,TRIP_ID_1
11:30,45,DEVICE_1,TRIP_ID_1
12:30,0,DEVICE_1,TRIP_ID_1
10:30,55,DEVICE_2,TRIP_ID_2
11:30,45,DEVICE_2,TRIP_ID_2
12:30,0,DEVICE_2,TRIP_ID_2
10:30,55,DEVICE_3,TRIP_ID_3
11:30,45,DEVICE_3,TRIP_ID_3
12:30,0,DEVICE_3,TRIP_ID_3
10:30,55,DEVICE_4,TRIP_ID_4
11:30,45,DEVICE_4,TRIP_ID_4
12:30,0,DEVICE_4,TRIP_ID_4
10:30,55,DEVICE_5,TRIP_ID_5
11:30,45,DEVICE_5,TRIP_ID_5
12:30,0,DEVICE_5,TRIP_ID_5
```

Comment: is there a technical term for this kind of sql approach ? like retrospective id'ing or something like that ?

Comment: Does involve a JOIN at the very least.

Answer (score 2):

An interesting problem. Had to fix one bug!

You will need to convert to spark.sql as I tried this in ORACLE. But WITH clause is supported in spark.sql. Also, instead of using date strings, due to the fact it is quite late I just used numbers to represent time, so you will need to look at that.

But here is the SQL that you can adapt.

```
with X as (select device, time_asc, trip_id from trips where trip_id is not null)
select Y.TRIP_ID, Y.DEVICE, Y.TIME_ASC FROM (
select T1.TIME_ASC, T1.DEVICE, X.TRIP_ID, X.TIME_ASC AS TIME_ASC_COMPARE
      ,RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY T1.TIME_ASC, T1.DEVICE ORDER BY X.TIME_ASC) AS RANK_VAL       from trips T1, X
 where T1.DEVICE = X.DEVICE
   and T1.TIME_ASC <= X.TIME_ASC) Y
 where RANK_VAL = 1
 order by TRIP_ID, TIME_ASC
```

Get rid of the order by, just used to show.

This data as input:

```
 ('1','A',null);
 ('2','A','TRIP_01');
 ('5','A',null);
 ('6','A',null);
 ('7','A',null);
 ('23','A','TRIP_02');
 ('56','A',null);
 ('60','A','TRIP_04');
 ('8','B',null);
 ('10','B','TRIP_03');
 ('1','E',null);
 ('2','E','TRIP_05');
```

removes quotes as I exported and got this format, returns the following, which I think will meet your needs - again excuse formatting:

```
 ('TRIP_01','A','1');
 ('TRIP_01','A','2');
 ('TRIP_02','A','5');
 ('TRIP_02','A','6');
 ('TRIP_02','A','7');
 ('TRIP_02','A','23');
 ('TRIP_03','B','8');
 ('TRIP_03','B','10');
 ('TRIP_04','A','56');
 ('TRIP_04','A','60');
 ('TRIP_05','E','1');
 ('TRIP_05','E','2');
```

Am wondering how well SPARK handles this with under the hood performance. This took some effort late at night, so some appreciation is sought. Enjoyable as well.

Comment: @blue - thanks for the effort, I will try it out and update

Comment: It works for sure. You can use a join instead of With

Comment: JOIN syntax may need to be explicit, I tend to use in IMPALA and SPARK ... LEFT JOIN ... etc.

Comment: @VinodhThiagarajan   : Can you state how you went on this? I am using it as a test case for performance of DFs.

Comment: @blue - I explained the complexity ( which was unnecessary for the domain I'm working o )n and fixed the issue w.r.t to data-source. I really loved your solution but I haven't used it as my req changed. Let me go upvote the solution.

Comment: success, but the answer is correct in the context of the question asked ...